# What is the source of this dua or hadith

Tags: source-identification

the wordings are as follows:

> "Oh Allah Guide the Nation of Muhammad. Oh Allah Bless the Nation of
>   Muhammad. Oh Allah remove all afflictions from the Nation of Muhammad"

It says whoever reads it ten times is written someone who is 'good'. Can You provide the source for it...even you don't have for the claim. I am sure this dua is from someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a du'a in the Quran and it's not a du'a from the Prophet.

It's a saying of Arif ar-Riwakri in 'Qadsa al-lahu Sirah' who was a Persian from Bukhara.

Comment: So does that mean what is said about person being listed as good can be false...or it has to be true. Who was he?

Comment: @MuhammadUmer sorry I didn't see your reply.  I don't understand the first part of your question.  Arif was just a poet, people overpraised him and gave him powers he didn't have.

Comment: But then this is a problem even if it appears that all was well intended. As there is no basis for claim that **whoever reads it ten times is written someone who is 'good'**. Or is there?

Comment: No there's no such proof for that claim.  The Prophet never said it, therefore it's completely made up without any facts.